# Check for Page Break in Tablix on rdlc

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Is there a way to check for page break in a tablix cell? I am working on a rdlc report and I don't want to show grid lines after each line, I only want to show a line if there is a page break. I am not controlling the page break. I know that you can set an expression for the border color property on the top and the bottom of a cell but I haven't been able to find anything on the web that indicates a way to check for page break.

This is what my report currently looks like:

[image: Current Page Break]

This is what I would like it to look like:

[image: Proposed Page Break]

Comment: did you try this solution: Put a solid line on the report footer. This line will close the box and give you your results. I have do some thing like this in the past.

Comment: @Hiten004 good point, never thought about trying that :)

Comment: I haven't but I will give it a shot and see. Thanks I will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some workaround to fix this problem.

Lets say that the table break after 60 rows, then you can define an expression that check when you get to the 60's row and to drow a border line.

In the Table's border properties, under the borderStyle just put the following expression

`=IIF(RowNumber("table1") Mod 60 , "Solid", "None")`

That way when the table reach to row 60K (K = 1,2,3...) the border will be solid, otherwise - none.

Comment: happy to hear, you wellcome :)

Comment: Looks weird. What if each row has different height and you don't know what is the last row on the page?